# Which iPad app does encrypted note storage?

Tags: ipad, applications

I'm wondering whether there's an iPad notes app that either:

1. doesn't back up to "the cloud", or
2. backs up an encrypted version of the notes such that the notes are unreadable in the cloud (i.e., a Dropbox employee couldn't read the notes).

Is anyone familiar with an app that allows for encrypted notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/ios) by Agile Bits may suit your needs and has just been updated to version 4. Sync your notes (and passwords) on the LAN to your other devices or via DropBox. (Only encrypted data is sent to Dropbox as per your requirement.)